# JQuery popup is not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to make a popup with JQuery and Javascript when a form is not filled in I want the popup to show up. But when I don't fill in the form and I click on the submit button its not working and there is no alert showing up.

This is my form code:

#### Vul deze gegevens in zodat wij voor u kunnen matchen

```
<form action="" id="form">

    <label for="locatie"><strong>Naar welke locatie gaat u op vakantie?*</strong></label><br>
    <br>
    <input class="form-input" type="text" id="locatie" name="locatie"required/>

    <br><br>
    <label for="datum"><strong>Welk datum?*</strong></label><br>
    <br>
    <input class="form-input" type="date" id="datum" name="datum" value="19/04-2018"required/>
    <br><br>
    <input class="form-input" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Versturen">
</form>
```

This is my Javascript/JQuery code:

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $('#submit').on('click',function()
    {
        if( $('input:required').val().length === 0 ) {
            alert('Vul alle velden in voordat u probeert te verzenden');
            return false;

        }

    });

</script>
```

In my head:

So what am I doing wrong? why is there no alert showing when I click on the submit button and the form is not filled in?

Any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: add `return false` after your alert message and where's `myMessage` element?

Comment: I did and still not working

Comment: that's because you dont have any element with id `myMessage`

Comment: Sorry that was my old code check my update I'm trying to do it like that now

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You are using css selectors wrong in your code

```js
      $('#submit').on('click',function()
        {
            if( $('input[type="text"]').val().length === 0 ) {
                alert('Vul alle velden in voordat u probeert te verzenden');
                return false;
               
            }
             
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Vul deze gegevens in zodat wij voor u kunnen matchen</h3>

        <form action="" id="form">

        <label for="locatie"><strong>Naar welke locatie gaat u op vakantie?*</strong></label><br>
        <br>
        <input class="form-input" type="text" id="locatie" name="locatie" value=""/>
        <br><br>
        <label for="datum"><strong>Welk datum?*</strong></label><br>
        <br>
        <input class="form-input" type="date" id="datum" name="datum" value="19/04-2018"required/>
        <br><br>
        <input class="form-input" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Versturen">
    </form>
```

Comment: if you don't have any code for these functions you can remove them from button onclick

Comment: I don'thave the sendMessage and clearInput functions anymore.. how can I make this work without those functions?

Comment: Still not working, I have to link put this link: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script> in the header right?

Comment: I think you already have jquery file reference, if not you can add this file reference in header

Comment: Yup but when I submit the form when its empty there is still no popup showing and I don't know why

Comment: please check your form code there should be no `onsubmit` function

Comment: I have no onsubmit function this is the only javascript/jquery function in my code:   $('#submit').on('click',function()
        {
            if( $('input:required').val().length === 0 ) {
                alert('Vul alle velden in voordat u probeert te verzenden');
                return false;

            }

        });

Comment: your form `<form action="" id="form">` is like this?

Comment: Yes sir it is like that

Comment: I edited my code. Well when I submit the form only the html required input field message is showing. Not the alert message of javascript/jquery. And when I remove the required attribute from the html form the page is refreshing without an error

Comment: I have updated my code to remove `required` attr dependency. Your code working for me

Comment: I copied your code in the function and also removed the required attributes but when I submit the form the page is still refreshing and no popup showing

Comment: try to add `return false` after if condition and then check if there is any error

Comment: What do you mean I already return false after the if condition like this? : if ( $('input[type="text"]').val().length === 0 ) {
                alert('Vul alle velden in voordat u probeert te verzenden');
                return false;
            }

Comment: move your return false after if condition